# Serilog UseSerilogRequestLogging logging after request, not before

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I followed this article https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore to set up the diagnostic message logged onto file by Serilog with.NET Core v5

My Configure method is as shown:

```
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(); //-> added this line as per docs

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

    /********** Authentication settings **********/
    // Don't move this code from here.
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    /********** Authentication settings **********/

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

I am using ILogger interface to log in all the layers of my web application. However; when i execute, the diagnostic logs from RequestLoggingMiddleware does not appear in order of execution as shown in below log sample:

```
2022-02-28 20:40:07.938 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.SomeService=  ******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******
2022-02-28 20:40:07.979 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 1896.5003 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:08.089 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.SomeService=  ******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******
2022-02-28 20:40:08.106 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.IIdentityServiceWrapper=  Profile Details fetched from Memory Cache 
2022-02-28 20:40:08.111 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 52.7317 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:08.150 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.SomeService=  ******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******
2022-02-28 20:40:08.154 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.IIdentityServiceWrapper=  Profile Details fetched from Memory Cache 
2022-02-28 20:40:08.155 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 27.4997 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:08.187 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.SomeService=  ******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******
2022-02-28 20:40:08.201 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.IIdentityServiceWrapper=  Profile Details fetched from Memory Cache 
2022-02-28 20:40:08.202 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 40.3553 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:09.156 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 403 in 2.6942 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:09.631 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 403 in 0.5469 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:09.659 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.SomeService=  ******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******
2022-02-28 20:40:09.662 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.IIdentityServiceWrapper=  Profile Details fetched from Memory Cache 
2022-02-28 20:40:09.662 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 25.4166 ms
2022-02-28 20:40:10.190 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.SomeService=  ******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******
2022-02-28 20:40:10.193 +05:30 [INF] MyApplication..API.Services.Interface.IIdentityServiceWrapper=  Profile Details fetched from Memory Cache 
2022-02-28 20:40:10.194 +05:30 [INF] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware=  HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 23.2961 ms
```

My Actual serial method looks something like this:

```
 private readonly ILogger<IService> logger;
 public List<Details> GetDownloadDetails(List<string> TransactionIdList = null, string limit = null)
 {
     logger.LogInformation("******Method: GetDownloadDetails Started*******");
 }
```

Hence, how do i make it to appear in order so that i can track when a thread enters and exists (assuming one 1 request at a time).

Comment: Can you explain a little more completely what you're exacly after ? the RequestLoggingMiddleware can only log when its all done as it logs the time taken?

Comment: As you can see in my service class method; i am logging a entry message whenever a request comes in from client.
Now since i have configured Middleware as well; i was expecting that middleware would get executed first and then the service method would get executed so in the log file output; same order would be followed. But the example i posted above, its not so

Answer (score 1):

The message

> HTTP GET /api/Download responded 200 in 1896.5003 ms

intentionally includes the time taken. That is obviously not known until it is complete. The benefit is that there is one message.

Hence, if you want a starting message, and to know the time taken, you'll have to take matters into your own hands, i.e.

- don't request that logging
- do something similar, but do it before the request

(IMO you should just live with it as it is though)

Comment: Hmm.. but i want the endpoint entry point added and then subsequent layers log messages logged in order so that when i analyze; i can easily go through logs. Assuming only 1 client at a time. How to do this? No i do not want to add log messagers in every controller endpoint method

Comment: Not suggesting adding a line per controller method. If you want to add context to all work performed for a request, `using LogContext.PushProperty` does that sort of thing - to be fair, this is where taking the time to talk about what you're expecting in the OP helps ;) There's an example of using it on https://benfoster.io/blog/serilog-best-practices/ (search for `RequestLogContextMiddleware`)